# Guice: Injecting a Module and then installing it

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Here's something weird.  Suppose you have a module like this:

```
public class ParentModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("key")).to("key");
    }
}
```

Then we also have something like this:

```
public class DependentModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final String key;

    @Inject public DependentModule(@Named("key") String key) { this.key = key; }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        // Configure bindings that make use of key...
    }
}

Injector parent = Guice.createInjector(new ParentModule());
Injector child = parent.createChildInjector(parent.getInstance(DependentModule.class));
// Now just ignore parent and work with child exclusively
```

This seems extremely cumbersome, but possibly necessary and useful in certain situations (if the key is a more complex datatype, for instance).  Regardless, is there a way to restructure this code such that `ParentModule` binds the key, creates the `DependentModule` using the key, and install the created `DependentModule`?  That is, such that the consumer can simply use a single injector instead of having to do this two-injector trick?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking.  Consider writing a SSCCE that illustrates what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to inject something and then install it.  Injection only happens after all your `configure()` methods have run, by which point it's too late.  But you can do this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("key")).to("key");
    }

    @Provides
    Dependency provideDependency(@Named("key") String key) {
        // Use key here
    }
}
```